# Error installing OMNET++5.1.1 on macOS10.15.6

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to install **omnet++ 5.1.1** to use with **Veins/Plexe** simulation. However, I am getting below error while compiling. I think I have followed the installation guide to get the additional packages in place but still no luck. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
    Creating shared library: /Users/safras/src/omnetpp-5.1.1/out/clang-release/src/qtenv/liboppqtenv.dylib
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::AutoTransform&)", referenced from:
          vtable for osgEarth::FindTopMostNodeOfTypeVisitor<osgEarth::Util::SkyNode> in osgviewer.o
          construction vtable for osg::NodeVisitor-in-osgEarth::FindTopMostNodeOfTypeVisitor<osgEarth::Util::SkyNode> in osgviewer.o
      "osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::Drawable&)", referenced from:
          vtable for osgEarth::FindTopMostNodeOfTypeVisitor<osgEarth::Util::SkyNode> in osgviewer.o
          construction vtable for osg::NodeVisitor-in-osgEarth::FindTopMostNodeOfTypeVisitor<osgEarth::Util::SkyNode> in osgviewer.o
      "osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::Geometry&)", referenced from:
          vtable for osgEarth::FindTopMostNodeOfTypeVisitor<osgEarth::Util::SkyNode> in osgviewer.o
          construction vtable for osg::NodeVisitor-in-osgEarth::FindTopMostNodeOfTypeVisitor<osgEarth::Util::SkyNode> in osgviewer.o
      "osg::NodeVisitor::NodeVisitor(osg::NodeVisitor const&, osg::CopyOp const&)", referenced from:
          osg::NodeVisitor::clone(osg::CopyOp const&) const in osgviewer.o
          virtual thunk to osg::NodeVisitor::clone(osg::CopyOp const&) const in osgviewer.o
      "osg::NodeCallback::run(osg::Object*, osg::Object*)", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osg::NodeCallback-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osg::NodeCallback::operator()(osg::Node*, osg::NodeVisitor*)", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osg::NodeCallback-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osg::GraphicsContext::WindowingSystemInterfaces::addWindowingSystemInterface(osg::GraphicsContext::WindowingSystemInterface*)", referenced from:
          omnetpp::qtenv::OsgViewer::OsgViewer(QWidget*) in osgviewer.o
      "osg::GraphicsContext::getWindowingSystemInterfaces()", referenced from:
          omnetpp::qtenv::OsgViewer::OsgViewer(QWidget*) in osgviewer.o
      "osg::DrawableEventCallback::run(osg::Object*, osg::Object*)", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osg::DrawableEventCallback-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osg::Callback::traverse(osg::Object*, osg::Object*)", referenced from:
          osg::Callback::run(osg::Object*, osg::Object*) in cameramanipulators.o
      "osgGA::EventHandler::event(osg::NodeVisitor*, osg::Drawable*)", referenced from:
          vtable for omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::OrbitManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::StandardManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::CameraManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::EventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osgGA::EventHandler::handle(osgGA::Event*, osg::Object*, osg::NodeVisitor*)", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::EventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osgGA::EventHandler::operator()(osg::Node*, osg::NodeVisitor*)", referenced from:
          vtable for omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::OrbitManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::StandardManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::CameraManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::EventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osgGA::GUIEventHandler::handle(osgGA::Event*, osg::Object*, osg::NodeVisitor*)", referenced from:
          osgGA::CameraManipulator::handle(osgGA::Event*, osg::Object*, osg::NodeVisitor*) in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "typeinfo for osg::DrawableEventCallback", referenced from:
          osg::DrawableEventCallback::isSameKindAs(osg::Object const*) const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::isSameKindAs(osg::Object const*) const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::isSameKindAs(osg::Object const*) const in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osg::DrawableEventCallback-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "typeinfo for osgGA::EventHandler", referenced from:
          osgGA::EventHandler::isSameKindAs(osg::Object const*) const in cameramanipulators.o
          non-virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::isSameKindAs(osg::Object const*) const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::isSameKindAs(osg::Object const*) const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::isSameKindAs(osg::Object const*) const in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::EventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "VTT for osg::NodeCallback", referenced from:
          osg::NodeCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::NodeCallback::clone(osg::CopyOp const&) const in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::NodeCallback::~NodeCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::NodeCallback::~NodeCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::NodeCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::NodeCallback::~NodeCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::NodeCallback::~NodeCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          ...
      "VTT for osg::DrawableEventCallback", referenced from:
          osg::DrawableEventCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::DrawableEventCallback::clone(osg::CopyOp const&) const in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::DrawableEventCallback::~DrawableEventCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::DrawableEventCallback::~DrawableEventCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::~DrawableEventCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::~DrawableEventCallback() in cameramanipulators.o
          ...
      "VTT for osgGA::EventHandler", referenced from:
          osgGA::EventHandler::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          osgGA::EventHandler::~EventHandler() in cameramanipulators.o
          osgGA::EventHandler::~EventHandler() in cameramanipulators.o
          non-virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::~EventHandler() in cameramanipulators.o
          non-virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::~EventHandler() in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::~EventHandler() in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::~EventHandler() in cameramanipulators.o
          ...
      "vtable for osg::NodeCallback", referenced from:
          osg::NodeCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::NodeCallback::clone(osg::CopyOp const&) const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::NodeCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::NodeCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
      NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
      "vtable for osg::DrawableEventCallback", referenced from:
          osg::DrawableEventCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          osg::DrawableEventCallback::clone(osg::CopyOp const&) const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
      NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
      "vtable for osgGA::EventHandler", referenced from:
          osgGA::EventHandler::cloneType() const in cameramanipulators.o
          osgGA::EventHandler::EventHandler(osgGA::EventHandler const&, osg::CopyOp const&) in cameramanipulators.o
      NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
      "non-virtual thunk to osgGA::EventHandler::event(osg::NodeVisitor*, osg::Drawable*)", referenced from:
          vtable for omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::OrbitManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::StandardManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::CameraManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
          construction vtable for osgGA::EventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "non-virtual thunk to osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "non-virtual thunk to osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "non-virtual thunk to osgGA::CameraManipulator::~CameraManipulator()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::CameraManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "non-virtual thunk to osgGA::CameraManipulator::~CameraManipulator()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::CameraManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osg::NodeCallback::run(osg::Object*, osg::Object*)", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osg::NodeCallback-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osg::DrawableEventCallback::run(osg::Object*, osg::Object*)", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osg::DrawableEventCallback-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osgGA::CameraManipulator::~CameraManipulator()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::CameraManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osgGA::CameraManipulator::~CameraManipulator()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::CameraManipulator-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
      "virtual thunk to osgGA::GUIEventHandler::~GUIEventHandler()", referenced from:
          construction vtable for osgGA::GUIEventHandler-in-omnetpp::qtenv::OverviewManipulator in cameramanipulators.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [/Users/safras/src/omnetpp-5.1.1/out/clang-release/src/qtenv/liboppqtenv.dylib] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [qtenv] Error 2
    make: *** [allmodes] Error 2
    bash-3.2$
```

Any experts out there much appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you changed something about your system halfway throughout building OMNeT++ (maybe reinstalling or updating library packages like `osg` or `open-scene-graph`)? If so, deleting your OMNeT++ directory and trying again might help. Otherwise, an incompatible or broken version of OSG might be to blame; if updating to another version of OSG is not an option, you might consider building OMNeT++ without OSG support by switching off WITH_OSG and WITH_OSGEARTH in its configure.user before running `./configure`

Comment: Hello Christopher, Thank you for the response.

Comment: 1] once I installed and working all good when I try to open the IDE then I faced an issue with error "An error has occurred " and IDE closes hence IDE cannot use at all. but Veins/PLEXE examples work fine.2] The problem with the IDE was java version I had was java 13 and the solution to downgrade to Java 8 will fix this issue. downgrade to java 8 and IDE original issue was gone but still some issue. then I try to reinstall omnet++5.1.1 got this issue tried with omnet5.6.2 same issue. I installed the whole open-scene-graph package but still no luck. I tried deleting the directory, no luck

Comment: However, building OMNeT++ without OSG support by switching off WITH_OSG and WITH_OSGEARTH in its configure.user file able to compile and works fine as a workaround for now.